# Change value of duplicates into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
id location_id company_id
1            1          1
2            2          1
3            3          1
4            4          5
5            5          5
6            6          5
```

The question is how to change all of values location_id to the lowest one in one company like this:

```
id location_id company_id
1            1          1
2            1          1
3            1          1
4            4          5
5            4          5
6            4          5
```

EDIT:
McNets code works, but I have another problem, this is my edited code:

```
update t1
set location_id = t2.min_loc
from opinion t1 
join (select company_id, min(location_id) min_loc
      from opinion
      group by company_id) t2
on t2.company_id = t1.company_id
join (select id, house_number, street, city
      from location) t3
on t3.id = t1.location_id
where t3.house_number is null and (t3.street is null or t3.street = '') and t3.city is null
```

Which is works on SQL Server 2016, but my database is MariaDB and I get an error

```
Syntax error near 'from opinion t1 join (select company_id, min(location_id) min_loc from op' at line 3
```

Any advice?

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Comment: Here's a hint: write a query that gets the lowest location ID for each company ID. Use that in a `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> create table tbl (id int, location_id int, company_id int)
> insert into tbl values
> (1, 1, 1),
> (2, 2, 1),
> (3, 3, 1),
> (4, 4, 5),
> (5, 5, 5),
> (6, 6, 5);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> update tbl t1
> join (select company_id, min(location_id) min_loc
>       from   tbl
>       group by company_id) t2
> on t2.company_id = t1.company_id
> set location_id = t2.min_loc;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | location_id | company_id
> -: | ----------: | ---------:
>  1 |           1 |          1
>  2 |           1 |          1
>  3 |           1 |          1
>  4 |           4 |          5
>  5 |           4 |          5
>  6 |           4 |          5
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=692e2cbf0c939f204bf47b589410185b)*

Comment: Thanks, it works, but i have another problem. Could you check my edit?

Comment: @pelkas13 I've edited my answer, now it works for MariaDb